# the rendered path shows a weird discontinuity where it jumps to (0,0)

Tags: qt, canvas, qml

I'm trying to build a widget that renders a dynamically generated `Path` in a `Canvas`, and also have a dot following that path using a `PathAnimator`. The problem is that although the dot moves in a circle as expected, the rendered path shows a weird discontinuity where it jumps to (0,0).

Screenshot of the path glitch, and the most relevant code snippets

[image]

Have I missed something, or is there a bug here?

Additional notes/clarifications:
 * I'm using Qt 5.5.1 (via PyQt5)
 * The end goal here isn't to just create a circular path. However, I'm trying to make sure the basic technique works correctly first, hence the circular path

Here's the full code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    id: base

    property real radiusMax : 200
    property real padding : 50

    property int duration: 15000
    property int numPoints : 12

    //property list<point> points


    width:  (radiusMax + padding) * 2
    height: (radiusMax + padding) * 2
    color: "white"

    /* The path that everything follows */
    Path {
        id: myPath

        // To be dynamically generated...
        //PathCurve { x: base.radiusMax; y: base.radiusMax } 
    }

    Instantiator {
        id: pathPoints
        model: base.numPoints

        property real angle  : (Math.PI / 180) * (360 / base.numPoints)
        //property real angle : 0.5235987755982988
        property real radius : base.radiusMax

        property point midpoint : Qt.point(base.radiusMax, base.radiusMax)

        onAngleChanged: console.log("angle = %1".arg(angle))

        delegate : PathCurve {
            x: pathPoints.midpoint.x + pathPoints.radius * Math.cos(pathPoints.angle * index)
            y: pathPoints.midpoint.y + pathPoints.radius * Math.sin(pathPoints.angle * index)
        }

        onObjectAdded: {
            console.log("Point %1 = (%3, %4)  <-- (%2)".arg(index).arg(index * pathPoints.angle).arg(object.x).arg(object.y))

            /* Update the list */
            if (index == base.numPoints - 1) {
                var items = []
                for (var i = 0; i < base.numPoints; i++) {
                    var obj = pathPoints.objectAt(i)
                    console.log("=> adding %1 = (%2, %3)".arg(i).arg(obj.x).arg(obj.y))
                    //if ((obj != null) || !(obj.x == 0 && obj.y == 0))
                        items.push(obj)
                }
                myPath.pathElements = items
            }
        }
    }

    /* Canvas: Used to render the path */
    Canvas {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width:  base.radiusMax * 2
        height: base.radiusMax * 2

        contextType: "2d"

        onPaint: {
            console.log("paint")
            context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
            context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(.4,.6,.8);
            context.path = myPath;
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }
  //}

    /* Dot that the participant is supposed to follow */
    Rectangle {
        id: targetDot

        // Start position - top-left of the canvas
        x: base.radiusMax
        y: base.radiusMax

        width: 20
        height: 20
        radius: 10

        color: "lightblue"

        PathAnimation {
            id: pathAnim

            running: true
            loops: Animation.Infinite

            duration: base.duration

            target: targetDot
            orientation: PathAnimation.RightFirst
            anchorPoint: Qt.point(targetDot.width/2, targetDot.height/2)
            path: myPath
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It jumps to (0, 0) because the default [start point](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-path.html#startX-prop) of `Path` is (0, 0). To draw the circular path, you need to assign the start point when path is generated. For example, use the first path point as start point:

```
Instantiator {
    id: pathPoints
    //....

    onObjectAdded: {
        if (index == base.numPoints - 1) {
            var items = []
            for (var i = 0; i < base.numPoints; i++) {
                var obj = pathPoints.objectAt(i)
                items.push(obj)
            }
            myPath.pathElements = items

            myPath.startX = items[0].x //assign start point
            myPath.startY = items[0].y //assign start point
        }
    }
}
```